# FlyoutLayout in FlyoutPage not appearing when FlyoutLayoutBehavior is set to Popover (works fine if it is set to Split instead)

Tags: xaml, maui, .net-maui

I have a FlyoutPage in which I want to have a 'Popover' flyout layout on the left and the detail page on the right. In other words, I only want the flyout on the left to show up if I click a button, and for it to remain hidden otherwise.

I believe that's what should happen if I set FlyoutLayoutBehavior to Popover. But when I do that, no flyout menu shows up at all on the left (the detail page on the right continues working fine).

If I set FlyoutLayoutBehavior to Split instead of Popover, it works as it should (the flyout is always visible on the left, splitting the screen).

What is wrong?

This is my xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FlyoutPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
            x:Class="MyApp.FlyoutPage"
            FlyoutLayoutBehavior="Popover">
    <FlyoutPage.Flyout>
        <local:FlyoutMenu x:Name="menu" />
    </FlyoutPage.Flyout>
    <FlyoutPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:Contacts />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </FlyoutPage.Detail>
</FlyoutPage>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a phone or tablet?  According to the docs, "The value of the FlyoutLayoutBehavior property only affects apps running on tablets or the desktop."

Comment: @thelsales, how did you navigate to the FlyoutPage? Doc page has two warnings. One that it won't work with AppShell (the default for Maui apps). The other that it won't work as a child of another page. Simplest way to use, is `Application.Current.MainPage = new MyFlyoutPage();`.  NOTE: You've named your FlyoutPage `FlyoutPage`. That may lead to confusion later, given that it has same name as the underlying Maui class; I would change its name. `MyFlyoutPage` or other name as desired.

Comment: @Jason I am using a windows desktop to run the app.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve to navigate to the page, I was using
 `Shell.Current.GoToAsync("MyFlyoutPage"); `.  This line is executed if a button is clicked on my MainPage, the button navigates to the FlyoutPage. I have replaced that line with `Application.Current.MainPage = new MyFlyoutPage()` as you suggested and the popover is now working as intended! Thanks.

Comment: To clarify: If you are using "Shell routes" anywhere in the app, then this approach may cause a problem later. Routes will no longer work, unless you set MainPage back to the AppShell. See the line in App.xaml.cs: `MainPage = new AppShell();`. That is required for Shell. If you don't use Shell at all, you can change App.Xaml.cs line to `MainPage = new MyMainPage();` (use the name of whatever page you show when app starts).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve in this case, would it not suffice to simply declare the new routes in the .cs file of the current page?

Comment: When you set `MainPage = new MyFlyoutPage();` that **completely wipes out AppShell**. There no longer is an AppShell running. So routes no longer have any meaning. Unfortunately, it isn't possible to use Shell (and routes) at the same time as a FlyoutPage. Because when you use Shell, it *is* MainPage - it runs your other pages inside of it. And FlyoutPage can't run that way. Thus the warnings in the doc. Your options are: **1)** Don't use FlyoutPage. or **2)** Don't use Shell and don't use Routes, or **3)** try to restore AppShell after using the Flyout Page. Caveat: I've never tried (3).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks for the informative reply. I will likely have to reengineer everything then. Makes me wonder why they even bothered to include a FlyoutPage then, half it's functionalities are missing and the other half don't work properly.